# Download PDF file in a folder via a react app

Tags: reactjs, pdf, amazon-s3

I am using S3 bucket to host my react application. I have a use case where I have to download a third party PDF file. For this I have an API that gives me the PDF file path ( a web URL). I want to download this PDF in a folder not sure how to do that.

Since I am getting the PDF file path only, I can only open this in a browser, but that is breaking my user experience.

I tried to use FileSaver npm package, but this also opens my pdf in a new window instead of downloading.

Here is a sample code

```
fetch('https://api.example.com/pdffile')
        .then(response => response.json()) //pdf file path
        .then(data => this.setState({ totalReactPackages: data.total }));
```